# How can I make a url like /united-states/cities/new-york

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rest, url-routing

How can I make a url like "/united-states/cities/new-york" intead of "/countries/1/cities/1" (I dont't want the word "countries" in the url)

what do I have to write in route.rb to use:

site.com/united-states/cities/ (to see united states' cities list)

site.com/united-states/cities/new-york/ (to see new york details)

and how use these routes in views and controllers?

Any ideas how to do this? cheers

Comment: I've found the rails guide on routing pretty useful: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html  I think what you are looking for is in section 4 Regular Routes.

Answer (score 1):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url

```
class Country
    def to_param
        @name
    end
end

class CountryController
    def show
        @country = Country.find(:name => param[:id])
        # ...
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks Maciej but I still confused with:

what do I have to write in route.rb to use:

site.com/united-states/cities/ (to see united states' cities list)

site.com/united-states/cities/new-york/ (to see new york details)

and how use these routes in views and controllers?

Comment: Sorry for delay. You set up the routes normally - only changes are in controller/model. All in detail is in podcast (link given).